# Cursor only retrieving one item, not all items

Tags: java, android, android-cursor

So I have used Cursor in my application to retrieve all tracks from the storage. The problem is that it is returning only one track not all the tracks. The code is perfect and no errors. Even I have tried accessing the ArrayList in which I am retrieving and storing all the tracks. The ArrayList's size is 1 instead of many. I am attcahing the code below:

```
private void Encrypt() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!= null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int TrackTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int Artist = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int Path = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        do{
            String Tracktitle = cursor.getString(TrackTitle);
            String Trackartist = cursor.getString(Artist);
            String Trackpath = cursor.getString(Path);
            arrayList = new ArrayList<CustomListView>();
            arrayList.add(new CustomListView(R.drawable.none, Tracktitle, Trackartist, Trackpath));

            CustomListViewAdapter customListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, arrayList);
            tracks.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);
            tracks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    

                }
            });

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

What the heck is wrong with code??

Comment: is cursor.moveToNext() false first time it's hit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `ArrayList` in each loop, move this line out of your do-while loop:

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<CustomListView>();
do {
   ...
```